# Curl code to R with postFrom or POST

Tags: r, curl, post, rcurl, httr

I've attempted to covert some curl code using both the postForm & POST methods in R following some other examples on here, however, i'm encountering 400 errors.

Here's the Curl i want to translate:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' --
header 'Accept: application/json' -d '[
  {

"campaignKwType":"DESTINATION_LANDMARK",
"featureId": 9849,
"guid": "xyz",
"language": "ENG",
"lob": "HOTEL",
"matchType": "EXACT",
"posa": "GBR",
"remarketingType": "NEW_CUSTOMERS",
"searchEngine": "GOOGLE",
"superRegionCampRef": true
 } ]' 'https://apiaddress'
```

With postForm:

```
   x <- postForm("https://apiaddress",
         .opts = list(postfields = toJSON(list(campaignKwType = "DESTINATION_LANDMARK", featureId = 9849,  guid = "xyz", language = "ENG", lob = "HOTEL", matchType = "EXACT", posa = "GBR", remarketingType = "NEW_CUSTOMERS", searchEngine = "GOOGLE", superRegionCampRef = TRUE)),
                      httpheader = c('Content-Type' = 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', Accept = 'application/json')))
```

With POST:

```
x <- POST("https://apiaddress",
               verbose(),
               encode = "json",
               body = list(c(campaignKwType = "DESTINATION_LANDMARK", featureId = 9849,  guid = "xyz", language = "ENG", lob = "HOTEL", matchType = "EXACT", posa = "GBR", remarketingType = "NEW_CUSTOMERS", searchEngine = "GOOGLE", superRegionCampRef = TRUE))
               )
```

Would appreciate any pointers, i've used other questions as an example for both of these requests and i've also checked the curl itself works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have the `c()` in your `list()` in the `POST` version but i'd imagine that's not what you want. Just use

```
x <- POST("https://apiaddress",
           verbose(),
           encode = "json",
           body = list(list(campaignKwType = "DESTINATION_LANDMARK", featureId = 9849,  guid = "xyz", language = "ENG", lob = "HOTEL", matchType = "EXACT", posa = "GBR", remarketingType = "NEW_CUSTOMERS", searchEngine = "GOOGLE", superRegionCampRef = TRUE))
           )
```

Comment: Removed the c() and still getting an error unfortunately: {"campaignKwType":"DESTINATION_LANDMARK","featureId":9849,"guid":"xyz","language":"ENG","lob":"HOTEL","matchType":"EXACT","posa":"GBR","remarketingType":"NEW_CUSTOMERS","searchEngine":"GOOGLE","superRegionCampRef":true}

<- HTTP/1.1 400

Comment: Exactly what error are you getting? Unless we can test it’s hard to help.

Comment: @Tim496 I missed the fact that your object was nested in an array. I've added an additional unnamed list around your list of values. Try that.